# node js - How to safely pass token from http get request to html page?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, security, passwords

I am working on implementing my own custom password reset that sends an email where the user is taking to a page to reset their password.

So far I have generated a unique token that gets put in an http get request link and emailed to the user.

When the user clicks the link (example `mywebsite.com/verifypasswordreset?id=96rZyAWLTu`)

I have an express route that gets the token:

```
//Verify Password Reset
app.get('/verifypasswordreset', function(req, res) {
    Parse.Cloud.run('verifyPasswordReset', { token: req.param("id") }, {
      success: function(user) {   
          res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + '/website/resetpassword.html'));
      },
      error: function(error) {
          res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + '/website/404.html'));
      }
    }); 
});
```

I then run a Parse cloud code function that validates if the token exists and if so it responds by sending the html that contains a form for resetting the password. (`resetpassword.html`)

At this point `resetpassword.html` page's url still has the token embedded in it (`mywebsite.com/verifypasswordreset?id=96rZyAWLTu`) however, as soon as the user submits the form, it does a http post and posts the new password, leaving the token behind in the link and thus I don't know which token is associated with the password reset?

```
//Reset Password
app.post('/resetpassword', function(req, res) {
    res.send('You sent the password "' + req.body.password + '".');
});
```

When the user submits the form to change their password, how can somehow get the token from the current url (`mywebsite.com/verifypasswordreset?id=96rZyAWLTu`) and include it in the http post request so my node js app can read it and knows which token is associated with the password reset?

Or alternatively, is their a better & safer way to keep track of the token?

*note ignore that I am using http I am going to buy an SSL certificate and use https before launch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see the point of validating the token when you are simply sending a resetpassword.html page. However, the token MUST be validated when actually updating the password for a user. So, here's a slightly modified workflow:

User clicks the link (example mywebsite.com/passwordreset?id=96rZyAWLTu)

```
app.get('/passwordreset', function(req, res) {
      res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + '/website/resetpassword.html'));
});
```

Your resetpassword page's URL still has the token embedded. Now, user submits the form, it does a http post and posts the new password.

```
app.post('/passwordreset', function(req, res) {
Parse.Cloud.run('verifyPasswordReset', { token: req.param("id") }, {
  success: function(user) {   
           //update user's password here
           res.send('You sent the password "' + req.body.password + '".');
  },
  error: function(error) {
      res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + '/website/error.html'));
  }
});
```

Comment: This doesn't solve the problem, after the user submits the form I don't have the token anymore. I just tried accessing `req.param("id")` when the user does the post request but it returns 'undefined'? How can I pass the token?

Comment: Does the full url with the token show up in the browser? If so, can you share your frontend code?

Comment: If you have <form action="/passwordreset">, that's obviously not going to work. Just use the <form> tag or have empty action.

Comment: That was it! i got rid of the action="passwordreset" thank you